# Script hangs when receiving data from socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, socketserver

This is my Python script to receive data from client:

```
import time
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 8888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as socketError:
    print('socket binding failed, ', socketError)
    print('Exiting...')
    sys.exit(0)

print('Socket binding complete')

s.listen(1)
print('Socket listening for connection...')

conn, addr = s.accept()

print('connected to ', addr[0])

bfr = b''
try:
    while True:
        while True:
            temp = conn.recv(1024)
            print('temp is ',temp.decode('utf-8'))
            print('buffer value ', bfr.decode('utf8'))
            if not temp:
                break
            bfr += temp;
        data = bfr.decode('utf-8')
        bfr = b''
        print('value received,', data)
        if data == 'Connection-Ready to receive commands':
            print('')
        #other conditions
except Exception as loopException:
    print("Exception occurred in loop, exiting...")
finally:
    s.close()
```

The script hangs up after printing
`connected to  192.168.4.197`
and is not accepting any commands from client. if the client disconnects, all the send commands are printed.

Why is it behaving like this?

### Update 1

Tried removing the inner while and added a `time.sleep(.10)` and the script is not hanging up but only the first command is printing as is and the rest is printing with a linebreak after the first character like, if I send 10, it will print 1 first and 0 in another line. All I want is to get the commands as it is sent from the client, every command is single word.

Comment: Your `try`/`except` suppresses every kind of exception. If you remove it, does it raise any errors? If so, please give a full traceback (though it may be obvious what's going wrong just from looking at it).

Comment: no it hangs up even without try except

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `sendall` to make sure the data is sent in its entirety from the client?

Comment: the client is java

Comment: In that case make sure the client calls `flush` to flush each command.

Comment: yes i have added flush after writing to output stream

Comment: tried adding delay with time.sleep(10) but it is only working only once